# Does that series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let us denote by $\langle x \rangle$ the distance between a real number $x$ and the closest integer to $x$ (for example, $ \langle \sqrt{2} \rangle =\sqrt{2}-1$). Does the series $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1 {(\langle\sqrt{2}k\rangle)^2k^2}$$
  converge or diverge?

Comment: Compare it with $\sum \frac{1}{k^2}$.

Comment: @ABC: $\frac 1 {(\langle\sqrt{2}k\rangle)^2k^2} \ge \frac 1 {k^2}.$ So what?

Comment: Well, the partial sums sure *look* like they diverge.